# zkemkeeper SetUserInfo isn't working

Tags: python

I want to create new user for the device through zkemkeeper.SetUserInfo(). However when I tried to use this function It always return False and when I look into the error code it said -2, Which means ERROR_IO. Anyone knows how to fix this thing or What could be the cause of this error ?
Here is my code

```
zk = Dispatch("zkemkeeper.ZKEM")
result = zk.Connect_Net(IP, PORT)
if result == True:
    result = zk.SetUserInfo(machineNumber, 456, "DEFG", 0, 0, True)
    print(result) #it always false here
    erroCode = zk.GetLastError()
    print(erroCode) # -2
    disConnectDevice(zk)
```

Comment: Have you solved this? You could specify which device you're using. Seems to me you're using a B&W Series device because of the `SetUserInfo()` function you're using. If you're using a TFT Series device you should use the `SSR_SetUserInfo()` function. You'll get the same error message if you call on a function with the device disconnected (not saying this is the case because it's clearly connected, just saying the error messages are vague). Another possibility is that the device's firmware is different than expected by the SDK (it has happened to me).

Comment: I have already solved this. It seems that I need to disable device with `EnableDevice()` before I use the `SetUserInfo()`. I don't know why it is the case but It works somehow.

Comment: can you explain more please , since you have solved ... thanks

Comment: So what I did is just add the line `zk.EnableDevice(machineNumber, False)` before using `zk.SetUserInfo(machineNumber, 456, "DEFG", 0, 0, True)` and after all of the function is done I just simply add `zk.EnableDevice(machineNumber, True)` again.